# Android - Sending/Receiving POJOs across Applications via Broadcast Receiver

Tags: java, android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

I am doing two Android Applications.

- Application 1 sends a Broadcast which has an "Extra" Custom POJO placed into it.
- Application 2 receives the Broadcast and gets the "Extra"(Custom POJO) and displays it.

Here is my Custom POJO in that implements Parcelable

```
 package com.steven.app1;

 public class Customer implements Parcelable {

    private int id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<Customer> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Customer>() {
        public Customer createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new Customer(in); 
        }

        public Customer[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Customer[size];
        }
    };

    public Customer(int id, String firstName, String lastName) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public Customer(Parcel source) {
        id = source.readInt();
        firstName = source.readString();
        lastName = source.readString();
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeInt(id);
        dest.writeString(firstName);
        dest.writeString(lastName);
    }
}
```

Application 1 then broadcasts like this

```
Intent i = new Intent("com.steven.app1.RECEIVE_CUSTOMER");
i.putExtra("customer", customer);
sendBroadcast(i);
```

In Application 2, I would receive the broadcast of Application 1 like this

```
package com.steven.app2;

public class CustomerBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Bundle data = intent.getExtras();
            Customer customer = (Customer) data.getParcelable("customer");
        }
    }

}
```

I get an error in the line

```
Customer customer = (Customer) data.getParcelable("customer");
```

because Application 2 does not have a Customer class

So I copied the Customer class of Application 1 and pasted it in Application 2 sources to remove the error. But after running the Application 2, shows up this error.

> "Class not found when unmarshalling:com.steven.app1.Customer"

So how would I get the Customer class in Application 1 and use it in Application 2?

Any help or suggestions would greatly be appreciated. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take *Customer* class and place it in a library project that can be referenced by the 2 app projects. Then, to make it easier you can implement the *Serializable* interface in the *Customer* class. Something like:

```
public class Customer implements Serializable{

/**
 * Auto generated
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = -559996182231809327L;
private int id;
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
public Customer(int id, String firstName, String lastName) {
    super();
    this.id = id;
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
}
// Add getters/setters here
}
```

Which is gonna be a much more simple and clean solution.

Your *onReceive(..)* method should look like:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Bundle data = intent.getExtras();
        Customer customer = (Customer) data.getSerializable("customer");
    }
}
```

To pass the data, pass it as a serializable extra and you should be good to go.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I followed your suggestion to place the Customer class in a project library and referenced it on both the apps. It Worked! But I did not used the Serialization though, the Parcelable works as well. Thanks

Comment: Glad to hear! Just keep in mind for future implementations that the *Serializable* interface is a faster way to go. I used to implement Parcelable, but it just makes harder to maintain huge classes. Regards.