# Sending serializable object between applications with broadcast receiver

Tags: java, android

Im trying to send an Object that implements "Serializable" from one application to another via a Broadcast receiver.

I want to send a class like:

```
public class MyObject implements Serializable{
    //basic properties
}
```

In application A i do this:

```
Intent i = new Intent("myApplication.string");
Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putSerializable("myclass",obj);
i.putExtras(b);
sendBroadcast(i);
```

When i debug this I can verify that the object is properly stored in the bundle in the intent.

In application B i do this:

**Manifest**

```
 <receiver
        android:name="com.example.myapplication.myreceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="myApplication.string"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

**Broadcast Receiver**

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    try{
        Bundle b = intent.getExtras();
        MyObject s = (MyObject)b.getSerializable("myclass");
    }catch (Exception e){
        Log.d(TAG,e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

In application B the intent does not hold the data that it did in application A.

When i try to cast the data it throws an:

```
Parcelable encountered ClassNotFoundException reading a Serializable object (name = com.example.myApplication.MyObject)
```

I've copied the class implementation in both application so they match.

[image]

In application A all the data is with in the mMap property of the Intent.extras - but in app B it is empty.

Can anyone help me understand this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Im trying to send an Object that implements "Serializable" from one application to another via a Broadcast receiver.

That is not a good idea. It requires both apps to have the same class definition for that Java class, or at least one that is compatible. Since the apps may not be updated at the same time, you can run into cases where the sender has a newer edition of the Java class than does the recipient, which can cause a deserialization exception.

> In application A i do this:

That is not a good idea. You are not sending the data to the other app. You are sending the data to any app that cares to listen for this broadcast, including any that may want to spy on your output.

> In application B i do this:

That is not a good idea. Any app can send a broadcast to this app, either to spoof messages or attempt to cause the app to crash. And on Android 8.0+, you will not receive the broadcast in any case.

> I've copied the class implementation in both application so they match.

Perhaps there is a problem in how you did this, as the error message would seem to disagree with your assessment.

I would start by getting rid of the `Serializable`. Only put things into extras that are guaranteed to be recognized correctly by all parties accessing those extras. So, use simple primitives, or `Bundle`, or other framework classes, not custom `Serializable` or `Parcelable` implementations. Then, see if your more ordinary extras are making it from app to app.

Then, do a better job of inter-process communication:

- Use an explicit `Intent` (one with a `ComponentName`), not an implicit `Intent` (one with an action string), so that the "broadcast" only goes between the two parties and works around the Android 8.0+ implicit broadcast restrictions
- Either implement permissions (e.g., `android:permission` on the `<receiver>`) or perform signature checks to ensure that the two parties are who you think they are

Comment: Good points...
Actually, I did try just to putExtra("test","test); in the intent and see if that got through and it didn't. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25757031/android-sending-receiving-pojos-across-applications-via-broadcast-receiver?rq=1) they infer the same as you point out and suggest to make a library shared between the two apps, which ill try.

Comment: @Simonk: "Actually, I did try just to putExtra("test","test); in the intent and see if that got through and it didn't" -- OK, that's strange. I cannot explain that.

Comment: It turned out to be the Bundle i was creating that messed it up. By adding the data directly as putExtra("key",val) instead, it worked. I cant tell you why, but the bundle i created an added as putExtras(bundle) didn't get through.. However you're right by pointing out the bad practice :)

Answer (score 0):

MyObject should implement Parcelable, not Serializable...

Comment: Why is that needed? You can send serializable objects between activities without any problems.

Comment: It should be working, but if not, it may be caused by nested Objects. If you implement Parcelable directly, there won't be any need for different implementations, your packaging class will know how to be parcelled and how to be deparcelled again...