# Android java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcelable encountered ClassNotFoundException reading a Serializable object

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to send the `Serializable` object from one application to another.

My android application has a serializable class

```
public class MyClass implements Serializable
```

and I then put one instance of it to the intent

```
MyClass myObject = new MyClass();
intent.putExtra("payItem", myObject);
intent.setAction("com.mypackage.some.action");
```

when I call startActiviy

```
startActivity(intent);
```

I got app crash

```
5-16 11:09:24.738 30673-30673/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: system:ui, PID: 30673
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{android/com.android.internal.app.ResolverActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcelable encountered ClassNotFoundException reading a Serializable object (name = com.mypackage.MyClass)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2955)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3030)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1696)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6938)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
 Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcelable encountered ClassNotFoundException reading a Serializable object (name = com.mypackage.MyClass)
    at android.os.Parcel.readSerializable(Parcel.java:2956)
    at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2742)
    at android.os.Parcel.readArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:3058)
    at android.os.BaseBundle.unparcel(BaseBundle.java:257)
    at android.os.Bundle.getParcelable(Bundle.java:888)
    at android.content.Intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.java:7734)
    at android.app.Activity.getReferrer(Activity.java:5398)
    at com.android.internal.app.ResolverActivity.getReferrerPackageName(ResolverActivity.java:554)
    at com.android.internal.app.ResolverActivity.onCreate(ResolverActivity.java:435)
    at com.android.internal.app.ResolverActivity.onCreate(ResolverActivity.java:331)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7174)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1220)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2908)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3030) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1696) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6938) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374) 
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mypackage.MyClass
    at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:453)
    at android.os.Parcel$2.resolveClass(Parcel.java:2942)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1616)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1521)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1777)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1354)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:374)
    at android.os.Parcel.readSerializable(Parcel.java:2950)
    at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2742) 
    at android.os.Parcel.readArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:3058) 
    at android.os.BaseBundle.unparcel(BaseBundle.java:257) 
    at android.os.Bundle.getParcelable(Bundle.java:888) 
    at android.content.Intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.java:7734) 
    at android.app.Activity.getReferrer(Activity.java:5398) 
    at com.android.internal.app.ResolverActivity.getReferrerPackageName(ResolverActivity.java:554) 
    at com.android.internal.app.ResolverActivity.onCreate(ResolverActivity.java:435) 
    at com.android.internal.app.ResolverActivity.onCreate(ResolverActivity.java:331) 
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7174) 
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1220) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2908) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3030) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1696) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6938) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374) 
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.mypackage.MyClass" on path: DexPathList[[directory "."],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/system/lib64, /system/vendor/lib64, /system/lib64, /system/vendor/lib64]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:93)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
    at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:453) 
    at android.os.Parcel$2.resolveClass(Parcel.java:2942) 
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1616) 
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1521) 
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1777) 
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1354) 
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:374) 
    at android.os.Parcel.readSerializable(Parcel.java:2950) 
    at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2742) 
    at android.os.Parcel.readArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:3058) 
    at android.os.BaseBundle.unparcel(BaseBundle.java:257) 
    at android.os.Bundle.getParcelable(Bundle.java:888) 
    at android.content.Intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.java:7734) 
    at android.app.Activity.getReferrer(Activity.java:5398) 
    at com.android.internal.app.ResolverActivity.getReferrerPackageName(ResolverActivity.java:554) 
    at com.android.internal.app.ResolverActivity.onCreate(ResolverActivity.java:435) 
    at com.android.internal.app.ResolverActivity.onCreate(ResolverActivity.java:331) 
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7174) 
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1220) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2908) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3030) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1696) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6938) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
```

Actually my phone has installed two applications with both register an activity 
with the same action name

```
<activity
        android:name="com.mypackage.MyActivity"
        android:exported="true"
        >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.mypackage.some.action"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

I would expect a dialog shown to let me choose which activity should be started, but I just got the error above. If I uninstall one of the applications, no error occurs and it runs as expected.

My question is

1. Why the dialog is not shown
2. Is it the reason of the crash
3. What's the solution to avoid that error if the two applications are both installed

Comment: Are you trying to send the Serializable object from one Application to another?

Comment: @Sagar Yes, that's what I want to do

Comment: @ArL In that case I think the target application doesn't know about your custom serialised object `MyClass`.

Comment: have a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32181516/android-java-lang-runtimeexception-parcelable-encounteredclassnotfoundexceptio

Comment: take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45373374/sending-serializable-object-between-applications-with-broadcast-receiver

Comment: Can you try using a bundle ? Something like this `Bundle serializable = new Bundle();`
 `serializable.putSerializable("key",myObject)`.

Comment: For now I'm using Gson instead of my own serialization, I will do more research after looking at your suggestions